# Unable to Replicate App Review Crash

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash-reports

I submitted my app for the first time to the App Store.  It was rejected because it crashed on launch.

I combed through the crash log but it is not clear to me why the app crashed.  I also deployed my binary using Ad Hoc and i was unable to replicate the crash.  Out of the 511 lines in the trace only one of my methods appears.  Below is the code from the method that appears in the crash log.  There isn't anything obvious to me as to why it would crash and it works fine on the device when using Ad Hoc.

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //    NSLog(@"error in loading banner");
    self.csBannerViewToolbarVerticalSpace.constant = - self.csToolbarHeight.constant - self.bannerView.frame.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // Called on parent view
                 }];
    self.adLoaded = NO;
}
```

Here is the crash log that apple sent me.  I include only the first 180 lines of the main thread trace.  It goes on for another 331 lines.

```
Incident Identifier: BEE5DBAE-78AA-4B7A-A00E-8FD2EC491E4E
CrashReporter Key:   45e776ed0586d581aba248bf3f23eaf42a231f2c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyApp [5844]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9A5F7578-CAB5-460D-A24E-F33646E3177D/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.MyCompany.MyApp
Version:             1.1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-04-29 10:54:14.160 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-04-29 10:54:08.513 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGILL)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016fcdffb0
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000019426e3e4 0x19425c000 + 74724
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000019426d060 0x19425c000 + 69728
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000019425d3e0 0x19425c000 + 5088
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000194261a00 0x19425c000 + 23040
4   CoreGraphics                    0x000000018260ae94 0x1825b4000 + 355988
5   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001825c55f0 0x1825b4000 + 71152
6   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001825c1730 0x1825b4000 + 55088
7   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001825c0708 0x1825b4000 + 50952
8   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x000000018297972c 0x182970000 + 38700
9   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x0000000182978b00 0x182970000 + 35584
10  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001825c0438 0x1825b4000 + 50232
11  UIKit                           0x0000000186dcd610 0x186dac000 + 136720
12  UIKit                           0x0000000186dcb5d0 0x186dac000 + 128464
13  UIKit                           0x0000000186dcab68 0x186dac000 + 125800
14  UIKit                           0x000000018710333c 0x186dac000 + 3502908
15  UIKit                           0x0000000186dca58c 0x186dac000 + 124300
16  UIKit                           0x00000001871d2d1c 0x186dac000 + 4353308
17  UIKit                           0x0000000186e13854 0x186dac000 + 424020
18  UIKit                           0x0000000186e79d7c 0x186dac000 + 843132
19  UIKit                           0x0000000186db975c 0x186dac000 + 55132
20  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186701e18 0x1866f4000 + 56856
21  QuartzCore                      0x00000001866fc880 0x1866f4000 + 34944
22  UIKit                           0x0000000186dcdf90 0x186dac000 + 139152
23  UIKit                           0x0000000186f25658 0x186dac000 + 1545816
24  UIKit                           0x0000000186f1d9f8 0x186dac000 + 1513976
25  UIKit                           0x0000000186f1bb30 0x186dac000 + 1506096
26  UIKit                           0x0000000186f168d4 0x186dac000 + 1485012
27  UIKit                           0x000000018711476c 0x186dac000 + 3573612
28  UIKit                           0x00000001872a76b4 0x186dac000 + 5224116
29  UIKit                           0x00000001872a7370 0x186dac000 + 5223280
30  Foundation                      0x000000018335c394 0x183188000 + 1917844
31  UIKit                           0x00000001872a76b4 0x186dac000 + 5224116
32  UIKit                           0x00000001872a7370 0x186dac000 + 5223280
33  UIKit                           0x00000001871dd144 0x186dac000 + 4395332
34  UIKit                           0x00000001872a76b4 0x186dac000 + 5224116
35  UIKit                           0x00000001872a7654 0x186dac000 + 5224020
36  UIKit                           0x00000001872a7370 0x186dac000 + 5223280
37  UIKit                           0x00000001871dc5a4 0x186dac000 + 4392356
38  UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
39  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
40  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
41  MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
42  UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
43  UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
44  MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
45  iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
46  iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
47  Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
48  UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
49  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
50  UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
51  UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
52  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
53  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
54  MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
55  UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
56  UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
57  MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
58  iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
59  iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
60  Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
61  UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
62  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
63  UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
64  UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
65  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
66  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
67  MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
68  UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
69  UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
70  MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
71  iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
72  iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
73  Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
74  UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
75  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
76  UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
77  UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
78  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
79  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
80  MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
81  UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
82  UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
83  MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
84  iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
85  iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
86  Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
87  UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
88  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
89  UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
90  UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
91  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
92  UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
93  MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
94  UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
95  UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
96  MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
97  iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
98  iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
99  Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
100 UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
101 CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
102 UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
103 UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
104 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
105 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
106 MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
107 UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
108 UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
109 MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
110 iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
111 iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
112 Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
113 UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
114 CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
115 UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
116 UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
117 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
118 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
119 MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
120 UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
121 UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
122 MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
123 iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
124 iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
125 Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
126 UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
127 CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
128 UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
129 UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
130 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
131 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
132 MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
133 UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
134 UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
135 MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
136 iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
137 iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
138 Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
139 UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
140 CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
141 UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
142 UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
143 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
144 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
145 MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
146 UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
147 UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
148 MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
149 iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
150 iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
151 Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
152 UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
153 CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
154 UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
155 UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
156 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
157 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
158 MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
159 UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
160 UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
161 MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
162 iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
163 iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
164 Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
165 UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
166 CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
167 UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
168 UIKit                           0x00000001870d8380 0x186dac000 + 3326848
169 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbca24 0x186dac000 + 68132
170 UIKit                           0x0000000186dbc990 0x186dac000 + 67984
171 MyApp                       0x00000001000537f0 __63-[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]_block_invoke (EBMainViewController.m:596)
172 UIKit                           0x0000000186df176c 0x186dac000 + 284524
173 UIKit                           0x0000000186df1564 0x186dac000 + 284004
174 MyApp                       0x0000000100053798 -[EBMainViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] (EBMainViewController.m:594)
175 iAd                             0x0000000187a500dc 0x187a4c000 + 16604
176 iAd                             0x0000000187a4fc00 0x187a4c000 + 15360
177 Foundation                      0x00000001831b547c 0x183188000 + 185468
178 UIKit                           0x00000001870906fc 0x186dac000 + 3032828
179 CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822a751c 0x182254000 + 341276
180 UIKit                           0x00000001871dc79c 0x186dac000 + 4392860
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to interpret my crash log and/or how to replicate the crash on my device.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like recursion or unconstrained looping to me. Have you followed these steps yet: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/_index.html ?

Comment: You are getting recursion into your method. It is being caused by the animation to layout `self.view`. I'd suggest symbolicating the crash report to learn more about what's happening. I'd also suggest testing this in development to see what happens when no ad is loaded in the development sandbox.

Comment: @BradBrighton I have followed those steps and was unable to replicate the crash.

Comment: You can control the ad fill rate for testing -- have you set it to 0% (ala the suggestion from @rmaddy)?

Comment: @rmaddy, as far as I know I did symbolicate using the steps described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html.  Should I be seeing something different that what I put in the post?

Comment: @BradBrighton I did reduce the fill rate to 0% using the developer section of settings on my device.  The app behaved the way i designed it and hid the add banner... no crash.

Comment: You should see class names and method names for all of the calls, not just your own code.

Comment: In that case Xcode doesn't seem to be symbolicating correctly.  I am using Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: Wow, six hundred lines of code — it's a lot, especially for the main view controller. Predictably that you've messed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely an infinite recursion. 
Try to fail ad loading, I'd start with something simple like turn off wifi/cellular data. Or you can replace your ad loading logic with manual failure — just call your own failure block instead of ad loading.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment.  I am using and `AdBannerView` which, according to apple docs says that it automatically loads an ad in the background.  I don't think I do anything myself to implement the loading of ads beyond what the api does.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. But tell me, what do you do in `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` ? Looks like adding a new AdBannerView

Comment: I am changing a auto layout constraint and then animating in order to move the `AdBannerView` off screen when an ad fails to load.

Comment: You are referencing your banner view like that `self.bannerView`. Please check, maybe you've implemented custom getter for that field and creating `AdBannerView` each time it references instead of just once?

Comment: @WeekendCodeWarrior please let me know did it helped or not

Comment: I retooled what i did in `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` from what i show above to something that doesn't animate.  I resubmitted the app to the App Store and it was approved on Friday.  I got lucky.  I still don't understand why my method was creating a recursion.